# Differential Drive Robot's Real Time Simulation of Movement in Rviz

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All. I have just started learning ROS and I am referring the book "Robot Operating System for Absolute Beginners" by Lentin Joseph. While going through the Chapter 6 of it that explains a Differential Drive Robot's development using ROS, I am running the example project on Melodic ROS. The robot is communicating with PC using Bluetooth and getting the movements based on keypresses. Rviz is also displaying the Robot's projected body. Now comes the real time movement simulation of the robot which I am not able to achieve, so I need to know what exactly the procedure is to get Differential Drive Robot's Real Time Simulation of Movement in Rviz.
Here are the nodes that are running currently:

- /robot_bt_driver_node
- /robot_state_publisher
- /rosout
- /rviz
- /teleop_keyboard
- /twist_to_motors

I know this is a homework kind of question which the forum does not allow, but I was not able to find correct keywords to search for the Real Time Simulation of Movement and hence I am putting a query here.

- Shaunak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303343/differential-drive-robot%27s-real-time-simulation-of-movement-in-rviz/) by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-09-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-09-14**:
I think you want to search for "real time visualization of movement" or something similar, since rviz is a visualizer and not a simulator.

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-14**:
Yes, I apologize for using the incorrect word simulation here. Visualization is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not familiar with the book you're using, but it might be as easy as choosing the right "fixed frame" option in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-22**:
@ahendrix: The "fixed frame" solution worked. Thank you. I kindly request to close the ticket now.